# Properties of Object not accessable

Tags: php

I'm quite new to OOP, so I got a little issue

I've created a class

```
class Lesson {
        function Lesson( $title, $sample ) {
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->sample = $sample;
        }
 }
```

Then an object

```
$title = 'title';
$sample = false;
$lesson = new Lesson( $title, $sample );
```

An when I'm trying to access a property of the object

```
echo $lesson->title
```

I get this error message

> "The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an
>   incomplete object..."

Comment: Try `echo $lession->{title} `

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? - what you've shown here looks a little archaic but it does actually work.

Comment: @CD001 I'm using PHP 7. What I need to do is to create a new object/array and then push it into an other array. Can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: PHP 7  *should* throw a `Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class...` error in this instance; using the class name as the function name for the constructor is deprecated in PHP 7 - it should be called `__construct()` as mentioned in the answers. You should also give it a scope, e.g. `public function __construct() { }` - it will default to public but it's untidy.

Comment: ... however - nothing you've shown *should* throw that specific error; that *seems* to be a serialization issue from a quick Google search (I've never run into it personally). I suspect the error is caused by something else in your code - storing the object in a session var or something.

Comment: @CD001 Thanks for the effort brother!

Answer (score 0):

Your properties aren't defined. Try adding them at the top of the class declaration.

```
class Lesson {
        public $title = '';
        public $sample = '';
        public function Lesson( $title, $sample ) {
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->sample = $sample;
        }
 }
```

The constructor syntax also depends on the verstion of php. If you are > 5.3.3 you should use `__construct()`

```
class Lesson {
        public $title = '';
        public $sample = '';
        function __construct( $title, $sample ) {
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->sample = $sample;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `function Lesson` to `function __construct` in order to pass those values on creation.

```
class Lesson {
    function __construct( $title, $sample ) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->sample = $sample;
    }
 }
```

Otherwise, you'd have to create it like this:

```
$lesson = new Lesson();
$lesson->Lesson($title, $sample);
echo $lesson->title;
```